# Apply %%capture to all cells to suppress all outputs, Jupyternotebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I would like to suppress all the output on my jupyternotebook.

I have learned that by putting %%capture magic keyword on the top of a cell, that cell won't produce any output. I would like to know how to apply this "%%capture" on to all the cells without physically writing them down on each cell.

FYI. I know how to clear output of all cells in jupyternotebook. I would like to know how to "suppress" the output. If you know any other way than, applying "%%capture" to all the cells, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sound likes a feature request. I submit it on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions/11186) for you.

Comment: Thank you, Ming. Is there any other way where I can suppress all the output without adding %% capture on all cell?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to meet your requirements in one step. However, I think one more step after operation can achieve the same effect:

We can use `clear outputs of all cells`. (This is only a clear output result, but it does not affect the cache of the cells have been run.)

[image]

**Tips:**

`%% capture` can store the object in your namespace.
You can refer to this [page](https://notebook.community/lifeinoppo/littlefishlet-scode/RES/REF/python_sourcecode/ipython-master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Capturing%20Output) for more details about `%% capture`

Comment: Does my solution solve your problem?